# Like Button social plug in code not working for browser..!

Tags: javascript, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Hi I am trying to run the same code on JSFIDDLE.NET and its working abs fine.
But When I run the code under body tag in browser it shows no result and error in chrome console:

In the end I want to same html file in webView on Android so that I can like a page.!
Failed to load resource file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=415120148602947
I think javascript is not running.
Code Goes like This:

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=415120148602947";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```